# Scipy fmin_cg is not iterating

Tags: python, scipy, gradient-descent, nonlinear-optimization

i've been reading lots of posts about how to use this routine, but i can't understand what i'm doing wrong, i have checked dimensions and the inputs, but i'm still in the same situation.

I need to optimize an objective function, with and without using its gradient (jacobian) matrix, when i run the code below the routine does not iterate, it says:

```
SciPy
Optimization terminated successfully.
         Current function value: 0.000000
         Iterations: 0
         Function evaluations: 1
         Gradient evaluations: 1

m0  : [  100   500 28000   500]
m: [  100   500 28000   500]
```

This is the code i have right now:

First attempt: This is without the gradient of the function

```
#Data
data = np.loadtxt('http://carina.fcaglp.unlp.edu.ar/~jgomez/academic/mpp/data/grav-cilindro2D-invertir.txt') 

x,d0= data[:,0],data[:,1]  # columnas del dato en cada vector (coordinate,anomaly)
d0=d0*1E-5 # m/s2

def gz_cilindro(m,x):
  #Constant
  G=6.67408e-11  #m^3/kg.s^2
  #
  ctte= 2 * np.pi * G 
  #
  gz=np.zeros(len(x))
  for i in range (len(x)):
    gz[i]= (ctte* m[0] * (m[1]**2) * m[3] )/ ((x[i] - m[2])**2 + m[3]**2) #m/s2
  #
  return gz

def cost(m,d0,x):
  #
  dc=gz_cilindro(m,x)
  #
  #Error vector
  e=np.zeros(len(dc))
  for i in range(len(dc)):
    e[i]=d0[i]-dc[i]
  #
  q = e.T@e
  #
  return q/2  #scalar

#
m0 = np.array([100, 500 , 28000, 500])   #Initial values
print('SciPy')
m = optimize.fmin_cg(cost,m0,fprime= None,args=(d0,x))
print(m)
```

Second attempt: This second version is using the gradient function which uses the same functions above:

```
def jacob(m,x):
    #Constant
    G=6.67408e-11  #m^3/kg.s^2
    fac=2 * np.pi *G         #Factor constante
    A=np.array([fac * m[1]**2 * m[3] / ( (x-m[2])**2 + m[3]**2 ),
              2* fac * m[0]* m[1] * m[3] / ( (x-m[2])**2 + m[3]**2 ), 
              2* fac * m[0]* m[1]**2 * m[3]*(x-m[2]) / (( (x-m[2])**2 + m[3]**2 )**2),
             fac * m[0]* m[1]**2 * ( (x-m[2])**2 - m[3]**2  ) / (( (x-m[2])**2 + m[3]**2 )**2)]).T
    return A


def grad_cost (m,d0,x):
  #
  dc=gz_cilindro(m,x)
  #Data
  N=len(d0)
  #
  #Error
  e=np.zeros(N)
  for i in range (N):
      e[i] = d0[i]-dc[i]
  #
  A=jacob(m,x)
  #Defino grad_q
  grad_q= -A.T@e  
  #
  return grad_q  #1D vector
#
m0 = np.array([100, 500 , 28000, 500])

print('SciPy')
m = optimize.fmin_cg(cost,m0, fprime= grad_cost, args=(d0,x))
```

I made my own code about steepest gradient, and i want to run this rountine in order to compare the results.

This is my first post here, i don't know if you need more information, if so, let me know and i update the question.

Again sorry for asking this, i try to solve my own things, but this one ...

Thank you so much and i hope you're having a good day.

Comment: The status looks like it happily detected convergence, probably because it deduced the gradient to be zero. Add some prints to your function (or debug it correctly) to see the invocation and it's output.  I did not check your formula, but `G=6.67408e-11` alone looks like trouble, due to bad scaling. If some solver is happily stopping with a gradient of `1e10^-8`, optimizing functions evaled to `1e-10` is obviously bad. Check this as explained above and probably scale ((x) ~ 1). This also covers numerical-differentiation.

Comment: omg you were completely right, i just changed the units (first they were in m/s^2 and now i put them in mGal) and now it is perfectly iterating. hehe i didn't know that these kind of things would happen by a simple constant. Thank you thank you sooo much. Have a good day!